# cordova media plugin status is not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, media

I want to know when the audio is still playing , and when it stopped to perform other actions . None of these options works for me. I tried for reproduce a same file, but only if is stopped, I try for a few days, but it still not work

```
function reproducirAudio(ruta) {
        var ruta = "/android_asset/www/sounds/button-1.mp3";
        $scope.media2 = new Media(ruta, function () {
            $scope.media2.play();

        }, function (b) {
        }, function (a) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(a));
        });

    }

function reproducirAudio(ruta) {
        var ruta = "/android_asset/www/sounds/button-1.mp3";
        $scope.media2 = new Media(ruta, bien,mal,status);
          function bien(){  $scope.media2.play();}
          function mal(){}
          function status(estatus){  console.log("status")}
}

function reproducirAudio(ruta) {
        var ruta = "/android_asset/www/sounds/button-1.mp3";
        $scope.media2 = new Media(ruta, bien,mal,status);
          function bien(){  $scope.media2.play();}
          function mal(){}
          function status(estatus){  alert(status)}
}

function reproducirAudio(ruta) {
        var ruta = "/android_asset/www/sounds/button-1.mp3";
        $scope.media2 = new Media(ruta, bien,mal,getStatusMessage);
          function bien(){  $scope.media2.play();}
          function mal(){}


     function getStatusMessage(status){

     if(status === 0){console.log('Media.MEDIA_NONE');}
         else if(status === 1){console.log('Media.MEDIA_STARTING');}
         else if(status === 2){console.log('Media.MEDIA_RUNNING');}
         else if(status === 3){console.log('Media.MEDIA_PAUSED');}
         else if(status === 4){console.log('Media.MEDIA_STOPPED');}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by creating a blank media player, then later setting the media. To test if it is playing just perform a check that tests if your media player is null or undefined.

```
$scope.media;
$scope.media = new Media("some/media/path.mp3);

if ($scope.media != null) {
    someAction();
}
else {
    otherAction();
}
```

Another option is to test if the media length is greater than 0.

```
$scope.media.getCurrentPosition(
    //success
    function (position) {
        if (position > 0) {
            console.log("A song is playing!");
        }
    },
    // error
    function () {
        console.log("An error occured!");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally it worked . I put this code and i realize a downgrade to cordova-media-plugin to 1.0.1 version

```
function reproducirAudioPorBoton(ruta) {
            var audiofile = new Media('file:///android_asset/www/sounds/M.mp3');
            audiofile.play();
            var counter=0;
            var timerDur = setInterval(function() {
                counter = counter + 100;
                if (counter > 2000) {
                    clearInterval(timerDur);
                }
                var dur = audiofile.getDuration();
                if (dur > 0) {
                    clearInterval(timerDur);
                    console.log(dur + " sec");
                }
            }, 100);
        }
```